# Getting the right envelope with KSOAP2

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I'm new to KSOAP2. Apparently I can't get the right type of envelope for a web service call in Android.

This is my code:

```
        private static final String METHOD_NAME = "wmtdEncApaLuces";
        private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/wsLucesAutomaticas/wmtdEncApaLuces";
        private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";
        private static final String URL = "http://softour.ddns.net:8083/wsLucesAutomaticas.svc/basic";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo strIp =new PropertyInfo();
        strIp.setName("strIp");
        strIp.setValue("192.168.1.121");
        strIp.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(strIp);

        PropertyInfo boolApaEnc =new PropertyInfo();
        boolApaEnc.setName("boolApaEnc");
        boolApaEnc.setValue(false);
        boolApaEnc.setType(boolean.class);
        request.addProperty(boolApaEnc);

        PropertyInfo strDispositivo =new PropertyInfo();
        strDispositivo.setName("strDispositivo");
        strDispositivo.setValue("Nexus 6");
        strDispositivo.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(strDispositivo);

        PropertyInfo strUsuario =new PropertyInfo();
        strUsuario.setName("strUsuario");
        strUsuario.setValue("John");
        strUsuario.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(strUsuario);

        PropertyInfo intTipoUs =new PropertyInfo();
        intTipoUs.setName("intTipoUs");
        intTipoUs.setValue(1);
        intTipoUs.setType(int.class);
        request.addProperty(intTipoUs);

        PropertyInfo intPuerto =new PropertyInfo();
        intPuerto.setName("intPuerto");
        intPuerto.setValue(85);
        intPuerto.setType(int.class);
        request.addProperty(intPuerto);

        PropertyInfo strIpConexionArduino =new PropertyInfo();
        strIpConexionArduino.setName("strIpConexionArduino");
        strIpConexionArduino.setValue("192.168.1.120");
        strIpConexionArduino.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(strIpConexionArduino);

        PropertyInfo intPuertoConexionArduino =new PropertyInfo();
        intPuertoConexionArduino.setName("intPuertoConexionArduino");
        intPuertoConexionArduino.setValue(1234);
        intPuertoConexionArduino.setType(int.class);
        request.addProperty(intPuertoConexionArduino);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = false;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Log.d("myTag", "Request: " + androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            // Log.d("myTag", "Response: " + response.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The generated XML for the SoapSerializationEnvelope is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<v:Envelope xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <v:Header />
   <v:Body>
      <n0:wmtdEncApaLuces xmlns:n0="http://tempuri.org" id="o0" c:root="1">
         <strIp i:type="d:string">192.168.1.121</strIp>
         <boolApaEnc i:type="d:boolean">false</boolApaEnc>
         <strDispositivo i:type="d:string">Nexus 6</strDispositivo>
         <strUsuario i:type="d:string">Alonso</strUsuario>
         <intTipoUs i:type="d:int">1</intTipoUs>
         <intPuerto i:type="d:int">85</intPuerto>
         <strIpConexionArduino i:type="d:string">192.168.1.120</strIpConexionArduino>
         <intPuertoConexionArduino i:type="d:int">1234</intPuertoConexionArduino>
      </n0:wmtdEncApaLuces>
   </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

I also tested it with SoapUI and it generated this XML, which is different from the one generated by KSOAP.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:wmtdEncApaLuces>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:strIp>192.168.1.121</tem:strIp>
         <tem:bolApaEnc>false</tem:bolApaEnc>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:strDispositivo>Nexus 6</tem:strDispositivo>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:strUsuario>John</tem:strUsuario>
         <tem:intTipoUs>1</tem:intTipoUs>
         <tem:intPuerto>85</tem:intPuerto>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:strIpConexionArduino>192.168.1.120</tem:strIpConexionArduino>
         <tem:intPuertoConexionArduino>1234</tem:intPuertoConexionArduino>
      </tem:wmtdEncApaLuces>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here's the definition http://softour.ddns.net:8083/wsLucesAutomaticas.svc/basic?singleWSDL

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Its about the namespace, look at this:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Now, look at this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
```

Namespaces are diferent. Try to add the right namespace in KSOAP Client, or better, handle properly the request in the .NET Web Service.

The next code Works, Try with HttPost instead KSOAP:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
StringEntity se;
String SOAPRequestXML = "";
try {
    SOAPRequestXML="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><tem:wmtdEstadoActuadoIluminacion><tem:strIp>192.168.1.121</tem:strIp><tem:strDispositivo>Nexus 6</tem:strDispositivo><tem:strUsuario>Alonso</tem:strUsuario><tem:intTipoUs>1</tem:intTipoUs><tem:intPuerto>85</tem:intPuerto><tem:strIpConexionArduino>192.168.1.120</tem:strIpConexionArduino><tem:intPuertoConexionArduino>1234</tem:intPuertoConexionArduino></tem:wmtdEstadoActuadoIluminacion></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
    se = new StringEntity(SOAPRequestXML, HTTP.UTF_8);
    se.setContentType("text/xml");
    httppost.setHeader("Accept-Charset","utf-8");
    httppost.setHeader("soapaction", SOAP_ACTION);
    httppost.setEntity(se);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    Log.e("RESPONSE: ", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

NOTE: Remember the AsyncTask in order to execute the request.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not an answer. Unfortunately, you don't have the rep to comment yet, but if you get a few upvotes on other questions, you will soon gain that privilege.

Comment: Thanks for the comment... Its my first time.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't let the downvote discourage you. Upvotes more than offset downvotes.